# How can I maintain bash functions without brittle escaped newlines?

Tags: linux, development-environment, bash

I have functions like this:

```
foo() {
    /some/script \
      --opt1=val1 \
      --opt2=val2 \
      --opt3=val3
 }
```

This is brittle if I take out the last option, or add any new option at any line. The failures are relatively silent, when I re-source the function, meaning I've run these wrong without noticing.

I use these functions by editing `.projectrc` then re-sourcing. Some of these mistakes lead to errors printed but they are relatively hard to notice. Any discrepancy between `type <fcn>` and the text in `.projectrc` should be a problem.

The escaped newlines are brittle and cause problems so I wonder a good alternative that lets me write a function not all on one long line without breaking so readily.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do specifically with functions - any kind of shell programming that involves long command lines is susceptible.

One helpful practice is to use `set -e`  in your scripts, so that errors don't just spit out an easily missed warning to STDOUT, but *stop the script*. Another is to add `\` to the end of **all** lines in a long option list, even the last one - it does no harm and makes it a bit easier to edit the option list later.